# Determining response length from an ISAPI filter

Tags: isapi

I am working on an ISAPI Filter to strip certain content out of responses.  I need to collect all the body of the response before I do the processing, as the content I'm stripping could overlap send buffers.

To do this I'd like to buffer the response content with each `SF_NOTIFY_SEND_RAW_DATA` notification until I get to the last one, then send the translated data.  I would like to know the best way to determine which `SF_NOTIFY_SEND_RAW_DATA` is actually the last.  If I wait until the `SF_NOTIFY_END_OF_REQUEST`notification, then I don't know how to send the data I've buffered.

One approach would be to use the content-length.  This would require I detect the end of the headers.  It would also require assuming the content-length header is correct (is that guaranteed?).  Since HTTP doesn't even require a content-length header, I'm not even sure it will always be there.  There seems like there should be an easier way.

I'm assuming the response is not chunked, so I am not handling dechunking before I do the response change.  Also, when I do the modifications to the response body, the size of teh response body will not change, so I do not need to go back and update the content-length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found some good discussions via google.

This posts answers my questions, as well as raises issues a more complicated filter would have to address:  http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.platformsdk.internet.server.isapi-dev/browse_thread/thread/85a5e75f342fad2b/cbb638f9a85c9e03?q=HTTP_FILTER_RAW_DATA&_done=%2Fgroups%3Fq%3DHTTP_FILTER_RAW_DATA%26start%3D20%26&_doneTitle=Back+to+Search&&d&pli=1

The filter I have s buffering the full request into its own buffer then using the SF_NOTIFY_END_OF_REQUEST to send the contents.  The modification it does does not change the size, and precludes the possibility that the response is chunked, so in my case the filter is relatively simple.